# In android application-The cursors for selecting the text is white and options for cut,copy,paste is also white, so that it is not able to see

Tags: android, android-studio

I am creating a new application and i am just a basic android programmer. I don't know the flows and need of xml's. But in eager i tried to create a basic application in android studio and works fine.

I check my app with different mobile devices. ASUS zenfone2 ZE551ml Motorola MOTO E and Sony Xperia. In every device the selection Cursor looks different.In asus and moto, cursors and cut,copy option visible. but in sony it is not visible.

I choose AppTheme as default.
Can anyone help me to overcome this  and to use correct theme to fit all devices, so that it makes me to learn something. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use custume style in your app as:

```
   <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
            <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
            <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
            <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
            <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
            <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
            <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
        </style>
```

and use color accent as the color you want for copy paste cursor .

```
 <color name="colorAccent">#FF4081</color>
```

Comment: May i know what action did "windowActionBar" and "windowNoTitle" performs?

Comment: they are just hide actionbar.